# Primefaces Clock component is not working as per the timezone attribute value

Tags: primefaces, timezone, clock

I have been using `primefaces` 6.2.RC2 and in one of my pages I need to show a clock with seconds ticking every second for the set timezone. For this I have been trying to use `p:clock` as shown below. The problem I am seeing is that when my timezone is set to EST, it still shows CST time. Looks like the timezone attribute is not working with whatever values set:

```
<p:clock pattern="HH:mm:ss" mode="server" timeZone="#{loginBean.timezone}"/>
```

Even I have tried using `f.convertDateTime` and that is also not working for the `<p:clock/>`. Is there any solution to fix this issue?

Comment: This component is client-side mostly javascript. Did you try debugging it?

Comment: HI I have tried it in server. It is working for other timezones but not for EST.

Comment: And why 6.2RC2? Not 6.2?

Comment: As we have been told that this latest version as there was a malware fix available  from primefaces we have upgraded. We were earlier using 6.1.

Comment: RC2 are release candidates. 6.2 the official final (community) release. Check the dates in the maven repo to confirm

Comment: Sure I will change the version to 6.2. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try America/New_York as the timezone?  EST is UTC - 5 hours. America/New_York is EST in the winter and E*D*T in the summer, so right now New York is UTC - 4 hours.

- CST = GMT-5
- EST = GMT-5
- EDT = GMT-4
- America/New_York = -4 in summer and -5 in winter and switched on daylight savings.

Comment: Yes yesterday I have tried with America/New_York and it is working. Thanks for your comments. This helped me.

Comment: Please upvote my answer and mark it as the "solution" then!